# Claim Check Set From A List of Clients

Tags: formatting, typography, templates, algorithms, programming

I don't know that this fits here, but here's my question:

I'd like to make a set of claim checks from a list of clients so that they can all be printed together within the same PDF.

I'm looking for a repeat algorithm that pipes in names and addresses, etc. and fills them into a claim check template, and repeats, say, 3 or 4 times per page, and then continues to the next page with the remaining clients. In the end, I seek to have a single PDF to print the entire claim check set with perforated cut lines between each check.

---

Extraneous: This doesn't have anything to do with the question at hand, but are there any counterfeiting measures that LaTeX offers that I can include in my claim check template?

---

*n.b.* - I don't actually have a template for the claim check I'd like to implement, but perhaps you might offer some typographic advice as to how I might go about designing the check. I know that I need my information somewhere, the claimer's, my business graphics, a check ID code, and some counterfeit measures.

Comment: The claim check will be used like a receipt from a pre-order purchase.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Easy job with `datatool` package. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a starting point using `datatool`. I won't discuss the design of the check (layout) as it is a candidate for a separate question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,textheight=5in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}   %% 5in only for demo
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{names.csv}
    number,Name,money
    1,Mr.\,Sreeram P.,12
    2,Mr.\,Rajaram K.,20
    3,Mr.\,Dhanraj Julien,35
    4,Ms.\,Lalitha S.,50
    5,Mr.\,Sreeram P.,2
    6,Mr.\,Rama Anvesh Reddy,400
    7,Ms.\,Shobana R.,65
    8,Ms.\,Archana D.,45
    9,Mr.\,Selvakumar R.,54
    10,Ms.\,Harthi M. G.,14
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}
%\sloppy
\DTLloaddb{names}{names.csv}
\pagestyle{empty}
\DTLforeach{names}{%
\name=Name,\money=money}{%
\par\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\vskip\baselineskip
This is to remember that\, {\bfseries\name}\,  has to give a sum of {\bfseries\$\money}\, to me which he is reluctant to give.

\vskip0.5\baselineskip
\hspace*{-1in}\makebox[\paperwidth][c]{\Huge\color{gray!40}\dotfill}
%% 1in is the left margin
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

My example shows how to do this task without any LaTeX packages. Suppose, we have the file `names.csv` in the format shown in Kumars answer.

```
% in preamble:
\newread\infile
\def\printletters #1 {\bgroup \endlinechar=-1
   \openin\infile=#1 \read\infile to\tmp \printlettersA
}
\def\printlettersA{\ifeof\infile \egroup \else
   \read\infile to\tmp
   \ifx\tmp\empty \else  \expandafter\printlettersB\tmp\par \fi
   \expandafter \printlettersA\fi
}
\def\printlettersB #1,#2#3#4,#5\par{\def\sex{#3}\def\name{#2#3#4}\def\money{#3}\printpage}

\def\printpage{%
   \bigskip
   This is to remember that {\bf\name}  has to give a sum of
   {\bf\$\money} to me which
   \if s\sex s\fi he
   is reluctant to give.
   \bigskip\hrule\bigskip % or \vfill\eject or...
}

% in document:
\printletters names.csv
```

Note, that the sex of the person is scanned from the second letter (Mr. or Ms.) and this information is used for the word "he" or "she".

Answer (score 2):

Shamelessly parasitic on Harish Kumar's data, this solution uses `textmerg` for the merge:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textmerg}%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{names.dat}
    Mr
    Sreeram
    P.
    12
    Mr
    Rajaram
    K.
    20
    Mr
    Dhanraj
    Julien
    35
    Ms
    Lalitha
    S.
    50
    Mr
    Sreeram
    P.
    2
    Mr
    Rama Anvesh
    Reddy
    400
    Ms
    Shobana
    R.
    65
    Ms
    Archana
    D.
    45
    Mr
    Selvakumar
    R.
    54
    Ms
    Harthi
    M. G.
    14
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\Fields{\honorific\surname\firstname\amount}
\Merge{names.dat}{%
  \hrule
  \bigskip\par
  \noindent This is a reminder that {\bfseries\honorific{} \firstname{} \surname{}} owes me the sum of {\bfseries\pounds\amount}.\bigskip\par
  \hrule}
\end{document}
```

[image: claim checks]